# Can we downgrade "bash: local: can only be used in a function" errors to warnings?

Tags: bash

Right now using `local` on the top level shell fails:

```
/tmp/tmp.TvdqDYLG9T$ local x=1
bash: local: can only be used in a function

/tmp/tmp.TvdqDYLG9T$ echo $x


/tmp/tmp.TvdqDYLG9T$
```

My rationale for wanting it to work is that I want to test my bash function by copy/pasting fragments of the code to the shell console and trying it out there. But I cannot, because of the `local`. I have to paste first to a notepad, remove `local` and then paste to the console.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why are you adding the `local` declarations at all? Can't you do that as the final step in developing the code? I mean, since `local` can only be used in functions, and since your development workflow seems to involve running the code _outside_ of its function enclosure, don't add the `local` declaration before you really have to.

Comment: The function has already been finished some time ago. But I want to make some changes and test them.

Comment: The best way to do this is have the function, and test invocations, in a file open in your editor. Then the workflow is simple edit, save, test, edit, save, test...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just a a one-off test, alias it away, e.g. with `alias local=`. Just remember to close that shell after you're done with the testing, since any later function definitions would be missing the `local` and that might bring some odd effects.

Alternatively, and more safely, alias `local` to `declare`, which pretty much works the same as `local` inside a function, but works on the top level too. So, `alias local=declare`.

Comment: "pretty much works the same" - can I use `declare` always instead of `local` in functions? Or should I stick to `local`?

Comment: @mark, I would use `local` since it makes the intent a bit clearer. It's also more widely supported in other shells, so there's that.